# SSRS Snapshot Filter UserID

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a large "Staff List" report from our HR system which I would like to Cache/Snapshot on a nightly basis to avoid daytime load on the HR DB.

I would like for the Snapshot to return all staff, in all departments, and then have the report filter the rows by department based on @UserID.

The data linking Users to allowed Departments is also in the HR DB.

I currently have 2 datasets. One for the Staff details and another linking Users to Departments.

- I assume I can't use @UserID in either dataset query and still cache/snapshot.
- I can't maintain a folder with linked reports for each Department, there are hundreds!
- Adding a Filter to the Datasets seems to prevent caching/snapshotting.
- I can't find a way to filter a Table with data from the Staff Details dataset using data in the Linking Dataset.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by Caching the (shared) dataset rather than the Report. The report parameters are therefore dynamic but the bulk of the data is drawn from an overnight cache.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a Cache Refresh Plan in combination with a Data Driven Subscription to preload the cache for the required Staff Details rows.

Here's the doco:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I think this is going to be the best solution. Seems a shame to cache hundreds of permutations of the report though. Any idea if the DB would be called multiple times?

Comment: Yes it would be.  You could just setup Cache Refresh and not the DDS, then only the 1st user waits. The real real solution is to get the report running in 5 seconds or so, on demand.